# jQuery get children text in tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html structure

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>DES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sub_mission_list">
        <tr>
            <td>Q1</td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T1</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q2</td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T2</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the value in `<textarea>`

I did and here is my solution, but I don't think it's a good way to do it. What's the best way to achieve that?

```
_.each($('#sub_mission_list tr'), function(value) {
  var describe = $($($(value).children()[1]).children()[0]).val();
  console.log(describe);
});
```

Comment: Use a `class` instead of an `id` (which isn't supposed to be duplicated in the same document) and you can use the class selector. `$('.mission_description', $value)`

Comment: iterate using each and get the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery.each()` for iteration, and use `.find()` to target `textarea`

```js
$('#sub_mission_list tr').each(function() {
  var describe = $(this).find('textarea').val();
  console.log(describe);
});
```

```js
$('#sub_mission_list tr').each(function() {
  var describe = $(this).find('textarea').val();
  console.log(describe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DES</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sub_mission_list">
      <tr>
        <td>Q1</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T1</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Q2</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T2</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Note: Identifiers in HTML must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `textarea` by updating the selector and use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over the jQuery collection.

```
// To get the textarea within the second td, update selector
// to more specific `$('#sub_mission_list tr td:nth-child(2) textarea')`
$('#sub_mission_list tr td textarea').each(function() {
  var describe = this.value; // get the text value
  console.log(describe);
});
```

```js
// To get the textarea within the second td, update selector
// to more specific `$('#sub_mission_list tr td:nth-child(2) textarea')`
$('#sub_mission_list tr td textarea').each(function() {
  var describe = this.value; // get the text value
  console.log(describe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DES</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sub_mission_list">
      <tr>
        <td>Q1</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T1</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Q2</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T2</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

---

In case you want to get the result as an array then use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method along with [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method.

```
var res = $('#sub_mission_list tr td textarea').map(function() {
  return this.value; // get the text value
}).get();
```

```js
var res = $('#sub_mission_list tr td textarea').map(function() {
  return this.value; // get the text value
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DES</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sub_mission_list">
      <tr>
        <td>Q1</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T1</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Q2</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T2</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use text area direct   `$('#sub_mission_list tr td textarea').each(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Use input type selector.

```js
$.each($('#sub_mission_list textarea'), function(value) {
  var describe =$(this).val();
  console.log(describe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>DES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sub_mission_list">
            <tr>
                <td>Q1</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T1</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Q2</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="mission_description" name="mission_description">T2</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can search in table using .find of jquery

```
    var getValues = $('#sub_mission_list').find('textarea');

    getValues.each(function(){
        console.log($( this ).val());
    });
```